# active of a Xlink anchor SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, fullpage.js

I have 4 anchor `xlink` inside my `SVG` and I want to get the active event of each, how can I call it in JS?

That looks like that:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thPage', 'lastPage'],
    menu: '#timeline',
    scrollingSpeed: 1000,
             onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
                  $('#bluecircle').css('stroke-dashoffset', (1510/4)*(4-(nextIndex-1)));            
          }
    });
    });
```

```css
html {
 image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor
}
body {
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 overflow:hidden;
 font-family: 'source_sans_prolight';
}

div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,
form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul, a {
 list-style:none;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.intro{
 font-size:20px;

}

/********** menu ************/
#header {
 position: fixed;
 right: -60px;
 top: 0;
 width: 60px;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
 -o-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
 transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
 -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, right; 
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 z-index:120;
}

#menu-burger-wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 left:-66px;
 top: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
 -moz-transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
 -o-transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
 transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1)
}

/********** essai************/
#menu-burger-wrappr.is-opened {
 -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
 -moz-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
 -o-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
 transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-276px);
 -moz-transform:translateX(-276px);
 -ms-transform: translateX(-276px);
 -o-transform:translateX(-276px);
 transform:translateX(-276px);
}

#menu-burger-wrappr.is-closed {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
 -moz-transform:translateX(0px);
 -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
 -o-transform:translateX(0px);
 transform:translateX(0px);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
 -moz-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
 -o-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
 transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}
 /**********essai************/

#menu-burger-wrapper.is-opened .line-burger {
 top: -35px;
}
#menu-burger-wrapper.is-opened .line-1 {
 -webkit-transform: translate(7px, 9px) rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform: translate(7px, 9px) rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform: translate(7px, 9px) rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: translate(7px, 9px) rotate(45deg);
 transform: translate(7px, 9px) rotate(45deg)
}
#menu-burger-wrapper.is-opened .line-2 {
 width: 0px;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(22px);
 -moz-transform: translateX(22px);
 -ms-transform: translateX(22px);
 -o-transform: translateX(22px);
 transform: translateX(22px)
}
#menu-burger-wrapper.is-opened .line-3 {
 -webkit-transform: translate(7px, -9px) rotate(-45deg);
 -moz-transform: translate(7px, -9px) rotate(-45deg);
 -ms-transform: translate(7px, -9px) rotate(-45deg);
 -o-transform: translate(7px, -9px) rotate(-45deg);
 transform: translate(7px, -9px) rotate(-45deg)
}
.line-burger {
 position: relative;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 1px;
 height: 35px;
 margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
 background-color: #c8c8c8;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
 -o-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
 transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1)
}
#menu-burger {
 width: 44px;
 background:#2C75FF;
 height: 32px;
 padding-top: 12px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#menu-burger.is-opened{
 z-index:999;
}
#menu-burger .line {
 width: 30px;
 height: 2px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 background-color: #fff;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(7px);
 -moz-transform: translateX(7px);
 -ms-transform: translateX(7px);
 -o-transform: translateX(7px);
 transform: translateX(7px);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
 -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
 transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1)
}
#menu-burger:hover .line-1 {
 width: 20px;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(12px);
 -moz-transform: translateX(12px);
 -ms-transform: translateX(12px);
 -o-transform: translateX(12px);
 transform: translateX(12px)
}
#menu-burger:hover .line-2 {
 width: 10px;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(27px);
 -moz-transform: translateX(27px);
 -ms-transform: translateX(27px);
 -o-transform: translateX(27px);
 transform: translateX(27px)
}
#menu-burger:hover .line-3 {
 width: 15px;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(7px);
 -moz-transform: translateX(7px);
 -ms-transform: translateX(7px);
 -o-transform: translateX(7px);
 transform: translateX(7px)
}

.is-opened #menu-burger:hover .line-1 {
 width: 20px;
 -webkit-transform: translate(12px, 9px) rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform: translate(12px, 9px) rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform: translate(12px, 9px) rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: translate(12px, 9px) rotate(45deg);
 transform: translate(12px, 9px) rotate(45deg);
}
.is-opened #menu-burger:hover .line-2 {
 width: 0px;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(22px);
 -moz-transform: translateX(22px);
 -ms-transform: translateX(22px);
 -o-transform: translateX(22px);
 transform: translateX(22px)
}
.is-opened #menu-burger:hover .line-3 {
 width: 20px;
 -webkit-transform: translate(12px, -9px) rotate(-45deg);
 -moz-transform: translate(12px, -9px) rotate(-45deg);
 -ms-transform: translate(12px, -9px) rotate(-45deg);
 -o-transform: translate(12px, -9px) rotate(-45deg);
 transform: translate(12px, -9px) rotate(-45deg);
}


.menu-base{
 background:#2C75FF;
 position: fixed;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 z-index:110;
 right: -300px;
}



.menu-base-open {
 right: 0px;
}

/**********push (class sur le body)************/

.push {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 position: relative;
 left: 0;
}

.push-toright {
 left: 240px;
}

.push-toleft {
 left: -240px;
}


.menu-base,
.push {
 -webkit-transition:all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
 -moz-transition:all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
 transition:all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}
/**********push (class sur le body)************/
 
.menu-item{
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:200px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size:100%; 
 overflow:hidden;
}
.menu-item a {
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 -webkit-transition:color 0.4s ease-in;
}

.menu-item a:hover, #en-cours{
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.menu-item li {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 margin-bottom:30px;
 margin-left:0px;
 vertical-align:middle;
 overflow:hidden;
 }


 /********** timeline ************/
#timeline{
 position:fixed;
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin-top:-250px;
 margin-left:-250px;
 pointer-events: all;
 z-index:99;
}

#titre{
 position:fixed;
 width:300px;
 height:100px;
 margin-top:-80px;
 margin-left:-150px;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 color:#FFF;
 text-align:center;
}

h3 {
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-size:50px;
}

#greycircle, #smallgreytop, #smallgreyleft, #smallgreybottom, #smallgreyright{
 stroke:rgba(204,204,204,1);
}
#bluecircle{
 stroke-dasharray:1510;
 stroke-dashoffset:1510;
 -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
 transition:all 1s ease;
}

#smallblueleft, #smallbluebottom, #smallblueright{
   stroke-dasharray:40;
 stroke-dashoffset:40;
  -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
 transition:all 1s ease;
}

#smallblueleft:hover, #smallbluebottom:hover, #smallblueright:hover{
 stroke-dashoffset:0;
}
 /********** section ************/
 

.fp-section {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fp-section.fp-table, .fp-slide.fp-table {
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.fp-tableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.fp-scrollable {
    overflow: scroll;
}
.fp-notransition {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}

h2{
 font-size: 2em;
}

#don{
 background-image: url(../image/1.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
}

#tri{
}




 /********** footer ************/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>

<!---------- timeline ----------->
   <div id="timeline">
   
 
   <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
<circle id="greycircle" fill="none" stroke="#727272" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="248.065" r="239.024"/>

<circle id="smallgreytop" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="8.643" r="4.976"/>

<circle id="smallgreyleft" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="488.875" cy="247.667" r="4.976"/>

<circle id="smallgreybottom" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="486.691" r="4.976"/>

<circle id="smallgreyright" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="10.826" cy="247.667" r="4.976"/>

<circle id="bluecircle" fill="none" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="248.065" r="239.024" transform="rotate(-90 249.85 248.065)"/>

<a data-offset="0" xlink:href="#firstPage"><circle id="smallbluetop" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="8.643" r="4.976"/></a>

<a data-offset="1132.5" xlink:href="#secondPage"><circle id="smallblueright" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="488.875" cy="247.667" r="4.976"/></a>

<a data-offset="755" xlink:href="#3rdPage"><circle id="smallbluebottom" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="486.691" r="4.976"/></a>

<a data-offset="377.5" xlink:href="#4thPage"><circle id="smallblueleft" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="10.826" cy="247.667" r="4.976"/></a>
      </svg>

 </div>
  
  <div id="fullpage">
 <div class="section " id="don">
  <h2></h2>
  <p></p>
 </div>
 <div class="section" id="tri">
   <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
  <p>Create Beautiful Fullscreen Scrolling Websites</p>
 </div>
 <div class="section" id="emploi">
   <h2>Example</h2>
   <p>HTML markup example to define 4 sections.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="section" id="recycle">
   <h2>Working On Tablets</h2>
   <p>Designed to fit to different screen</p>
   </div>
            
            <div class="section" id="vente">
   <h2>Working On Tablets</h2>
   <p>Designed to fit to different screen</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? What do you want to be able to do in javascript? I worked up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/6cpew3sc/) of one way to capture click events on the links, but I don't know if that's even close to what you're asking.

Comment: each "<a xlink></a>" are anchor of a section of the page and i need to add the "active" class on each one for make a style in css

Comment: actually i want to make a timeline like when i scroll to #secondpage the second button dash array appear, when i m on 3rdpage the third button dash array appear and the second stay appear too ( sorry for my english ) :p

Comment: I think I had it backwards, then. I thought you wanted the links to activate different sections when clicked. Actually, you want to add or remove a CSS class on each link based on the scroll position of the document. Is that correct?

Comment: [I updated my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/6cpew3sc/1/). Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: perfect thank you for take time to resolve my problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up pulling in the (nearly) ubiquitous jQuery library to get this to work across browsers (adding and removing classes on IE is really counter-intuitive). The basic idea is to declare a function that will check if the user has scrolled passed the top of the section of interest for a given `Xlink`, and then call that function on each link every time the user scrolls. In code, this may look like:

```
var svg = $("#svg");
var main = $("#main");
var links = $("a");
var numLinks = links.length;

function setXlinkActive(xlink, scrollY) {
  var section = $(xlink.attr("xlink:href"));
  var clientY = section.offset().top;
  if (scrollY > clientY) {
     xlink.show().addClass("active");
  } else {
     xlink.removeClass("active").hide();
  }
}
```

Now, this function needs to be called for each `Xlink` on each `scroll` event inside the `main` element:

```
main.bind("scroll", function() {
    var scrollY = main.scrollTop() + main.offset().top;
    links.each(function(idx, link) {
        setXlinkActive($(link), scrollY);
    });
});
```

Mess around with [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/qqptjkct/2) to see what works for you.

Comment: i m trying to use it with a full page js http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/  and actually it s look that i can t get the it with this script

Comment: Why didn't you mention that in your question?

Comment: i was thinking that i had the degree for include what you did .. but actually … no :/

Comment: I was not aware of fullpage.js. It looks like it's pretty easy to use. Why not just use that? What's the extra feature you're trying to add?